# monitor specific process in linux bash script goal is to perform top for each process and not all together

Tags: linux, bash

I have this script and i want to monitor specific processes and not all together how can i grep specific process to ?

```
#!/bin/bash
# rsync using variables
Interval=60
Count=62000
Path=~/MyScripts/monitor

cd $Path
> `hostname`_top.log
date >> `hostname`_top.log
top -b -d $Interval n $Count  >> `hostname`_top.log
```

Comment: What about `top | grep -e process1 -e process2 ...` ?

Comment: `top  -b -d "$Interval" -n "$Count" |grep -P "^$PID "` ?? or use `-p pid` flag of `top` command to monitor specific process.

Comment: yes but then when I want to insert it inside a file it gives me empty file

i did as following:
top -b -d $Interval n $Count | grep -P $ENGINE_PID >> `hostname`_top.log

when $ENGINE_PID is a process id i took before

Comment: Where are you setting $ENGINE_PID in the script?

Comment: like this:
ENGINE_PID=$(ps -ef | grep 'engine' | tail -5 | head -1 | awk '{ print $2 }')

Comment: I suggest that you run the script with -x to ensure that all the variables are getting expanded correctly.